# Access dependency property in ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, dependency-properties

I have user Control named LoggingControl which has dependency properties called ParentID and DocumentType.

I used user control as child control in one of my another user control which is parent.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Local:LoggingControl  
        ParentID="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedCRM_T001A.CatNo,
                      Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                          AncestorType={x:Type Local:WindowElement}}}" >
    </Local:LoggingControl>
</Grid>
```

dependecy properties:

```
public partial class LoggingControl : UserControl
{   
    public LoggingControl()
    {          
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new COM_T002_VM();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentIDProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("ParentID", typeof(int?), typeof(LoggingControl),
      new PropertyMetadata(0));        

    public int? ParentID
    {
        get { return GetValue(ParentIDProperty) as int?; }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ParentIDProperty, value);
        }
    }       
}
```

and I want access my dependency properties in my View Model ( ie . COM_T002_VM ).  How can I bind them together so I can access them from within my ViewModel whenever they change?

Comment: "i want access my dependency properties in View Model". You certainly don't want to do that, because it would break the MVVM pattern, where the view model should not know the view. Your view model should instead declare equivalent properties, then you could create two-way bindings to update view and view model properties in both directions.

Comment: actually i want values of that dependency properties in my view model.

Comment: if i declare properties in view model.where should i give this two way binding

Comment: i have checked that using

Comment: Text="{Binding ParentID,RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Mode=TwoWay}"

Comment: but now i want set this value to view model's property

Comment: What is Text? Is it the Text property of a TextBox?

Comment: The binding in your XAML also looks dubious. If you assign `DataContext = new COM_T002_VM()` in your control's constructor (which is questionable by itself), you would write the binding expression as `ParentID="{Binding Path=SelectedCRM_T001A.CatNo, ...}`, assuming that the `COM_T002_VM` class has a `SelectedCRM_T001A` property.

Answer (score 3):

if you create "real" UserControls with Dependency Properties you should **never** to this:

```
 this.DataContext = new COM_T002_VM();
```

this is breaking Datacontext inheritence!

what you should do is some sort of relative binding (ElementName or RelativeSource):

```
 <UserControl x:Name="myLoggingUc">
  ...
   <!-- you always bind in your UserControl to the DPs! -->
   <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=myLoggingUc, Path=ParentID, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

using anywhere outside:

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <!-- the DataContext here should be your Viewmodel with a Property SelectedCRM_T001A -->
    <!-- And this Property should have a Property CatNo, now its working-->
    <Local:LoggingControl  ParentID="{Binding Path=SelectedCRM_T001A.CatNo,Mode=TwoWay}" />
 </Grid>
```